# This is my code below and its showing incorrect syntax. Any idea why and what to do?

Tags: sql-server

```
select 
    'WO-' + OrderNo + 'LN-' + convert(nvarchar(10), OrderLine) + 'BN-' + convert(nvarchar(10),
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY id, OrderNo))  as orderno,                 
    distinct PartNo, opno, Quantity, 
    requiredPartno, requiredquantity, level
from 
    VW_batching
```

Comment: You can't use `distinct` like that, please read usage of `distinct` keyword - where and how to use them.

Comment: Why can't we use DISTINCT there? Please explain in detail......

Comment: He is telling about 'distinct PartNo' @Arman

Comment: when i am using :-select distinct partno from VW_batching,,,,,its working fine....can you tell me how to correct it sir

Comment: i think its taking distinct on a set of columns,but if i place it on the last,it still shows the same

Comment: The problem is the column `orderno` before `DISTINCT` keyword. You cannot select any column before `DISTINCT`. Every column should be stated after `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

I think Problem is With "DISTINCT" Only As some mentioned In Comments

Let me explain you briefly,

I had a table named `'tblBilling'`

When I executed "`SELECT * FROM tblBilling`" the Output is:-

```
EngID   Tower   Billing Amt
100      ICS    Y   5000
100      EDT    Y   7777
100      ICS    N   2000
```

Now when I used "`SELECT DISTINCT EngID , Tower FROM tblBilling`" the output :-
is:-

```
EngID   Tower
100     EDT
100     ICS
```

But When I used "`SELECT Tower,Distinct EngID FROM tblBilling`" It shows me an error:-

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Distinct'.
```

So When we have multiple columns in select Statement Write Distinct Column first and next write the rest.
Try This:-

```
select distinct PartNo,'WO-'+ OrderNo + 'LN-'+ 
convert(nvarchar(10),OrderLine) + 'BN-'+ convert(nvarchar(10),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY id, OrderNo))  as orderno,                 
 opno, Quantity, requiredPartno, requiredquantity, level
from VW_batching
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about this, but I think it is a problem with the non-case-sensitivity of T-SQL.

You are using `OrderNo` as column and assign a allias named `orderno` to another column.

Try something like:

```
select 'WO-'+ OrderNo + 'LN-'+ 
convert(nvarchar(10),OrderLine) + 'BN-'+ convert(nvarchar(10),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY id, OrderNo))  as  dispatchNo,                 
distinct PartNo, opno, Quantity, requiredPartno, requiredquantity, level
from VW_batching
```